# sqlite connection from swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a problem with this library sqlite: https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData

I have used this code to insert into table value:

```
    let name: String = "test" //user input
    let population: String = "test"//user input 

    if let err = SD.executeChange("INSERT INTO Users (Name, Surname) VALUES (?, ?)", withArgs: [name, population]) {
        //there was an error during the insert, handle it here
    } else {
        //no error, the row was inserted successfully
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Error During Prepare -> SQLITE Code: 1 - SQL error or missing database

Answer (score 0):

The library [SwiftData](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData) was very recently updated to print a more detailed error message. Did this give you more information on your error?